# Override a := in another makefile

Tags: make

Say I have a makefile called Foo, and it has a variable called Bar.

in Foo I have:

```
Bar := /some/initial/path
Other_var := ${Bar}/more/paths
```

and then in my main makefile I use Foo

```
include Path/to/Foo
```

But How can I make it such in my main makefile I can set Bar and have my value of Bar be the one used in Foo? I tried using eval but the `:=` is a real challenge. A big goal is to not change the source of Foo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My GNU make 4.0 online info says if you use the `override` keyword on an assignment, normally used to override command line *var=value* settings, then the value will not be changed by further assignments which do not use the `override` keyword.

So you could try in your main makefile:

```
override Bar := myvalueforbar
include Path/to/Foo
```

Comment: Yes! this was correct, override was my next thought to try out too

Answer (score 1):

If you define `Bar` before including `Foo` in your `Makefile`, then the Bar is available in `Foo`.

E.g. I have the following in each of my `Makefile`'s for Python packages (the first two lines differing per Makefile of course):

```
UTILNAME:=yaml
PKGNAME:=ruamel.yaml
VERSION:=$(shell python setup.py --version)

include ~/.config/ruamel_util_new/Makefile.inc
```

And in the `Makefile.inc` I have generic routines that among other things now how to create  a distribution file:

```
DIST:=dist/$(PKGNAME)-$(VERSION).tar.gz
WHL:=dist/$(PKGNAME)-$(VERSION)-py*-any.whl

$(DIST): $(SRC)
        make check
        python setup.py sdist
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question.  Your `Makefile.inc` doesn't (re)define `PKGNAME` or `VERSION`.  The OP's `Foo` (subordinate makefile) *does* (re)define `Bar`, and he has a goal of not modifying `Foo`.

Comment: as I understand it the OP wants to know how to create Makefile and Foo so that Foo doesn't need changing after that even if Bar changes.

Comment: Well, we interpreted the question differently.  The answer that the OP accepted suggests that my interpretation was correct (which seems to happen slightly more than 51% of the time    :-)    ).